# Unable to pip install librosa in raspberry pi 3 model b+ (Raspbian stretch)

Tags: software-installation, python-3, pip

Respected people,

Attempt 1: 
when I run the command,

```
pip3 install librosa
```

I am stuck here,

```
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... \
```

It was taking more then 2 hours but it was still continuing the same, finally it was built , but i get a lot of error after that

Attempt 2:

I saved these in requirements.txt and ran the command

pip install -r requirements.txt

```
>>> import librosa
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from .audio import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 12, in <module>
    import resampy
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/resampy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/resampy/core.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .interpn import resample_f
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/resampy/interpn.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numba
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .decorators import autojit, cfunc, generated_jit, jit, njit
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/decorators.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .targets import registry
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/targets/registry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import cpu
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/targets/cpu.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .base import BaseContext, PYOBJECT
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/targets/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numba import _dynfunc, _helperlib
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

How can I solve this ? please help!

audioread==2.1.5
cryptography==1.7.1
decorator==4.0.11
idna==2.2
joblib==0.11
keyring==10.1
keyrings.alt==1.3
librosa==0.5.1
llvmlite==0.15.0
numba==0.30.1
numpy==1.12.1
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygobject==3.22.0
python-apt==1.1.0b5
pyxdg==0.25
resampy==0.2.0
scikit-learn==0.19.0
scipy==0.18.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.10.0
virtualenv==15.1.0

In Raspbian buster I got the following!,This should not be fatal!!

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import librosa
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py:9: NumbaDeprecationWarning: An import was requested from a module that has moved location.
Import requested from: 'numba.decorators', please update to use 'numba.core.decorators' or pin to Numba version 0.48.0. This alias will not be present in Numba version 0.50.0.
  from numba.decorators import jit as optional_jit
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py:9: NumbaDeprecationWarning: An import was requested from a module that has moved location.
Import of 'jit' requested from: 'numba.decorators', please update to use 'numba.core.decorators' or pin to Numba version 0.48.0. This alias will not be present in Numba version 0.50.0.
  from numba.decorators import jit as optional_jit
```

Comment: Hi Sundar - I see you're new here, welcome :-)  Have you _considered_ the advice the error message gives? ("**Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.**") And if so what did you try?  Rather than trying to butter people up ("Respected people") it'll generally be more effective if you show some initiative / willingness to rule out the sensible things first (even if that's more work for you than just asking others) as that makes people more motivated to help you (since you won't come across as lazy - not that I'm saying you are...)

Comment: Yeah i tried that out too.. but still I have errors !

Comment: @Neil  Do you have any idea why do I get the above error? thanks!

Comment: What did you find out about the file permissions? I see you've changed the error message with no indication of what you changed in your approach (this reduces the value of this question for others who run into your initial problem). You also still don't include sufficient detail about your setup to help someone to help you

Comment: As well as the points above, how about including the output of **pip list**? My guess is that it'll relate to the version of numpy you've got (or possibly other packages)

Comment: I have included my requirements.txt , includes all my libraries . About the previous one “- - user” solved it! I also tried replacing to the latest version of numpy , but i dont think librosa is compatible with latest one!

Comment: Thanks Sundar. This is starting to be helpful. Your requirements.txt contains librosa - but then you say you're running pip3 install librosa. Which order are things being done in here and are there any failures with your pip install requirements.txt? And is it really pip or pip3 you're using with requirements?

Comment: Now I have very well differentiated it. My first attempt was pip3 install librosa  and I got some issues while installing related to llvmlite( i dont even know what is that). As that was unsuccessful I saw a conversation in stack overflow and downloaded the requirements.txt to use the command pip install -r requirements.txt . Note these two methods are independent and before going to the second method i did a pip3 uninstall librosa !

Comment: Thanks. That's clearer. I've got an idea of the likely issue and fixes now - I did recently get librosa (Inc llvmlite,a requirement) installed on an RPi 4. I'll try to write up an answer this evening or tomorrow evening.

Comment: @Neil Sir, when I try to install this , 

sudo apt install llvm

It is showing me llvm-3.8 , also I tried to give a command 

sudo apt install llvm-7 ( After upgrade and update)

E: Unable to locate package llvm-7
This was the result

Comment: same when i tried sudo apt install llvm-7.0

Comment: Ah - I see that you're on Raspbian Stretch. Several of the packages in that are relatively old, so I think it won't have the necessary version of LLVM. Are you stuck on Stretch or could you migrate? (it's been out now for 10 months now)

Comment: I am very concerned only about librosa. I can surely migrate. But I am not sure whether I can use buster in 3B+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is with numba, as you'll see with the last two lines of the trace:

```
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/targets/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numba import _dynfunc, _helperlib
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I had this issue myself when installing librosa recently on a Raspberry Pi.

---

Despite the numba issue, let's start with a few basics first as you ultimately want to install librosa:

- this will be easiest to manage if you do it in a virtual environment

  - I'll leave that to you and [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+install+python3-venv)
  - main advantage is any mistakes from previous steps are less likely to cause you grief!
  - if you don't go for a virtual env then be sure to clear out all the related python packages you pip installed so you've got a clean base
- getting llvmlite installed
- installing a suitable version of numpy for numba
- installing the rest (ie librosa and all the remaining dependencies)

**Note:** I suggest you install a newer version of librosa than the one in your requirements.txt (or you'll run into issues where the official recommendation is update to 0.6!)

### llvmlite

The python package llvmlite is needed by numba, which in turn is needed by librosa.

The llvmlite package depends on the OS package LLVM (it's a compiler/toolchain) and it requires a specific version of LLVM ([more info here](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite#compatibility)). Fortunately we don't need to compile it from scratch as currently the version in Raspbian is version 7.0 so you can install it by running the following:

```
sudo apt install llvm
```

(just be sure to confirm that the version installing is 7)

Then find out where **llvm-config** was installed with:

```
which llvm-config
```

And paste that result into this *LLVM_CONFIG=**/path/to/llvm-config** pip3 install llvmlite* for me results in:

```
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip3 install llvmlite
```

Leave that to install.

At some points the output will shown mention of failures, but then runs setup.py and ends with these lines:

> Failed to build llvmlite
>
> Installing collected packages: llvmlite
>
> Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... done
>
> Successfully installed
>
> llvmlite-0.32.0

You can double-check things worked to this point with:

```
python -m llvmlite.tests
```

which will run tests and reports "OK (skipped=3)".

### numpy / numba

I found that numba would install but did not work (giving the error you observe) when I had numpy 1.15.x installed. Also to get it to install from piwheels you need

```
sudo apt install libatlas3-base
```

Then run this:

```
pip install numpy==1.16.1 numba
```

The output indicating it completed should be:

> Successfully installed numba-0.49.0 numpy-1.16.1

When that completes, in python try **import numba** - it *should* succeed (ie show no error, just the next prompt) but if not then there's no point in proceeding until the issues at this point are resolved.

### Installing the rest

From here on you should be okay just installing librosa. This is the point where I suggest 0.6.2 (or newer if reading this later).

```
pip install librosa==0.6.2
```

You will see the output pull in various files from PiWheels / PyPI.  It should end with a success message:

> Successfully installed audioread-2.1.8 decorator-4.4.2 joblib-0.14.1 librosa-0.5.1 resampy-0.2.2 scikit-learn-0.22.2.post1 scipy-1.4.1 six-1.14.0

You can now see if it imports in Python.  **Note:** you'll likely see a Deprecation Warning message but it shouldn't be fatal.

Also depending on what you want to actually do with librosa you may run into issues with the backend etc (eg if you test it with the first tutorial: https://librosa.github.io/librosa/tutorial.html#quickstart)  That's beyond the scope of this answer but in that case, you may want to install ffmpeg (see https://github.com/librosa/librosa#audioread-and-mp3-support / `sudo apt install ffmpeg` )

From the look of your requirements.txt you may have some additional packages you want to install but if you're just after librosa then you should be done.

---

Hope that helps!  I just re-tested it on a 100% freshly installed image of Raspbian Buster Lite (version: Feb 2020).

Let me know in the comments if you run into further problems.  And don't forget to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: After following this I got some warnings which is posted above

Comment: I think as mentioned warrnings shouldn't be fatal! I have to thank you so much as this is the best resource available to install librosa in RPi by far!!!

Comment: Yes, it looks like that's a warning regarding future compatibility. Glad you got it working in the end :-)

Comment: Confirming this still works for the newest Librosa 0.8.0! Fantastic instructions. By far the simplest! Now to get LLVM 8 or higher to work..!

Comment: I had to install llvm-9 to get this working ("RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 10.0.x or 9.0.x, got '7.0.1'.").

Comment: @Austin did you do any other changes to the above procedures while downloading librosa 0.8.0 ?

Comment: @SundarKrishna It's been awhile, but here are some instructions I wrote for myself (each line is separated by a comma, so run them separately):

sudo apt-get install llvm,
LLVM_CONFIG=/user/bin/llvm-config sudo pip3 install llvmlite==0.32.0,
sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base,
sudo pip3 install numba==0.49,
sudo pip3 install librosa,
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1

Comment: @SundarSanthanam I recently tested today with the newest Pi4 firmware and Python 3.9. LLVM now defaults to version 11.  You can either specify LLVM7 on install and follow my old instructions or you can use LLVM11 with llvmlite==0.37.0 , numba==0.54.1 , and numpy==1.20.3 .