# librosa on a raspberry pi

Tags: python-3, software-installation

I have a problem with librosa installation on raspberry pi. I followed the instructions from the comment @Austin from:
[Unable to pip install librosa in raspberry pi 3 model b+ (Raspbian stretch)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111697/unable-to-pip-install-librosa-in-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-raspbian-stretch)

I installed llvmlite == 0.37.0, numba == 0.54.1, and numpy == 1.20.3 with LLVM11 (python 3.9.2)
It seems to have installed well, I can import numba without errors, but when I try to import librosa I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from .time_frequency import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/core/time_frequency.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/util/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/librosa/util/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    from ._filters import *  # noqa: F401 F403
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import _nd_image
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your numpy version is too new? I faced such issues when installing librosa yesterday. I had to go figure out the correct package versions to install librosa. The below worked for me.

First install numpy, numba, scipy using apt.

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy python3-numba python3-scipy
```

The required llvm devs, tools etc. and python3-llvmlite should get installed with the numba install.

Then install librosa with a requirements file and without dependencies. We don't want to upgrade dependencies because they may not work.

First make the requirement.txt file.

```
sudo nano requirement.txt
```

Paste the below content into the file.

```
librosa==0.9.2
audioread==3.0.0
resampy==0.2.2
scikit-learn==1.2.2
packaging==23.1
pooch==1.7.0
soundfile==0.12.1
joblib==1.2.0
decorator==4.4.2
platformdirs==3.5.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
cffi==1.15.1
pycparser==2.21
```

The install using pip.

```
pip install --no-deps -r requirement.txt
```

Check if it has worked by opening python and importing librosa and maybe load an audio file.